# Change popups (notifications) style in Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

I installed xUbuntu 16.04 and the popups have unreadable (for me) white-on-light-grey color scheme. To make things worse these popups are transparent.

I can't find a setting to change this color. Changing style in Appearance settings doesn't seem to affect popups.

[image: popups are unreadable]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the properties of the "pop-up" notifications via the "Notifications" settings. These are under the Settings tab:

[image]

Additionally, you can invoke this through the terminal, with the following command:

```
xfce4-notifyd-config
```

Both alternatives open the following window:

[image]

This has basically everything you need.